# Restoring multiple files to multiple database with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, scripting, syntax

I have multiple dump files and want to restore them with single command. something like this

```
pg_restore  -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres 
    -d gl_election gl_world gl_tourism 
    -c "gl_election" "gl_world" "gl_tourism"
```

This command doesn't work and I can't find how to do it correctly. It works fine for one file.

Comment: Why are you providing 3 arguments to the -d flag, you're trying to load up three databases with pg_restore?

Answer (score 1):

`pg_restore` doesn't take multiple filenames, nor multiple databases (-d) end of story. So use a simple shell loop. I assume you're trying to

1. Clear out the old database
2. Load up a dump to the database with the same name

That loop will look like this

```
for dump in gl_election gl_world gl_tourism; do
  echo Clearing and reloading "$dump"
  pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d "$dump" -c "$dump"
done;
```